# In advanced collections module in python 2.7. What is the difference between Counter(dict(c.items)) and dict(c)

Tags: python

```
//This is the code

sen = 'How many times does each word show up in the sentence word word shows up up shows'

words = sen.split()

c = Counter(words)

dict(c)

Counter(dict(c.items()))
```

//Output

```
//output of dict(c)

{'How': 1,
 'does': 1,
 'each': 1,
 'in': 1,
 'many': 1,
 'sentence': 1,
 'show': 1,
 'shows': 2,
 'the': 1,
 'times': 1,
 'up': 3,
 'word': 3}


//output of Counter(dict(c.items()))

Counter({'How': 1,
         'does': 1,
         'each': 1,
         'in': 1,
         'many': 1,
         'sentence': 1,
         'show': 1,
         'shows': 2,
         'the': 1,
         'times': 1,
         'up': 3,
         'word': 3})
```

Comment: The stupid answer is "one is a `dict` object and one is a `Counter` object." I'm not sure what you want to know other than that. Counter implements all the dict methods so I'm not sure what casting one to the other buys you, but that's what was done here.

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs about [Counters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). They're generally used for tallying only. It provides other operations that aren't available with vanilla `dict`'s.

Comment: I'm new to python. Actually the output was same in both the cases so I wanted to know is there any difference between the two? Like do they behave same if same operations are used on both of them and what are the scenarios where i need to implement them?

Comment: Read the docs: 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict

Comment: Thanks for the help